# What's the English name for this algebraic operation? $ab=ac → b=c$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

In Hebrew, the operation of deducing $$ab=ac \Rightarrow b=c$$ is called "צימצום" [tsimtsum] which translates roughly to "elimination" or "reduction"

More specifically for non-abelian groups the above formula would be "Right-elimination" or "Right-sided elimination", and $$ ba=ca \Rightarrow b=c$$ would be "Left elimination"

What is the accepted terminology for this in English?

Comment: What about simply 'cancelation'?

Comment: Just saying: This deduction is possible only if you know for a fact that $a ≠ 0$ 
$$ba=bc$$

$$a(b-c)=0$$

$$a = 0 \ or \ b=c$$

And your question has nothing to do with "Abstract Algebra". Please remove that Tag.

Comment: Are you sure your terminology has correct chiralities? You've said we call elimination of a factor from the left right-elimination.

Comment: @RishiNandhaVanchi I'm currently studying a course called "Algebraic Structures" which is the topic of this question, but I couldn't find an "Algebraic Structures" tag, so I thought `abstract-algebra` would be a close enough fit. is this not the case?

Comment: Simply Algebra would be better? Yes Abstract-Algebra is very related unlike I thought.

Comment: `The 'algebra' tag is not allowed.

Please choose a more specific tag, for instance abstract-algebra or algebra-precalculus.`

Comment: @Toldry: may I emphatically point out that what you are inquiring about here is not an operation (at least not in the formal mathematical sense, where by operation we mean algebraic law of composition of a certain arity) but **a property** that a certain algebraic structure (a multiplicative magma) might have or not.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I was using the word operation informally because I didn't quite know how to phrase the question

Comment: Though I'm not English native, I too have always seen in Algebra book in English the wording "(left/right) cancellation law".

Comment: See e.g. Wiki [Cancellation Property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property). This is the most common name in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is called the (left or right) cancellative property.

If you're talking about groups, you can describe the operation as pre-multiplying (or post-multiplying) by $a^{-1}$.  In monoids or semi-groups with the cancellative property, you cannot describe it like that because $a^{-1}$ does not formally exist, so you just call it applying the cancellative property.